# Synchronously HTTPS GET with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

So I'm trying to preform a `https GET` with `node.js`and I have the following code

```
function get(url) {
    https.request(url, function(res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data)); 
        });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }).end();
}
```

This code works fine and dandy except I need this function to return the data its logging

I know the recommended way to do this is to use callbacks, passing a callback function into `get` and then calling that function in the `'end'` listener. But the problem is that this process needs to be synchronized and NOT pipelined because it causes data hazards and uses too much memory. On top of that, its is recursively called and is just one big headache to try and manage.

Basically, I'm trying to `return JSON.parse(data)` in the `get` function then the `end` listener is called, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I recommend [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). It is specifically designed to help you fight the famous pyramid of callbacks in JavaScript. I understand that callbacks can lead to less-readable code but you should not try to make synchronous get requests. It kind of defeats the advantages of node.js.

You can convert

```
step1(function (value1) {
    step2(value1, function(value2) {
        step3(value2, function(value3) {
            step4(value3, function(value4) {
                // Do something with value4
            });
        });
    });
});
```

to this -->

```
Q.fcall(promisedStep1)
.then(promisedStep2)
.then(promisedStep3)
.then(promisedStep4)
.then(function (value4) {
    // Do something with value4
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})
.done();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't synchronously return data using an asynchronous function to retrieve the data.  Your `get()` function will return long before the `https.request()` has completed so you just can't do what you asked to do.

The usual design pattern for solving this involves passing in a callback function to your `get()` function that will be called when the data is available.  This will involve restructing the caller of your function to handle an asynchronous response via a callback function.

There are some different choices in how you structure the callback, but here's the general idea:

```
function get(url, callback) {
    https.request(url, function(res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            callback("success", JSON.parse(data));
        });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
        callback("error", e);
    }).end();
}
```

Usage:

```
get("http://www.example.com/myurl", function(status, data) {
    if (status === "success") {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand how to use callbacks, the problem is more so that the callbacks become hellish and unwieldy because the main structure is recursive. I'm wondering if there's a way to call HTTPS GET requests that aren't asynchronously called

Comment: @user3381026 - it sounds like you want blocking network operations.  I do not think node will do that (it breaks the whole node paradigm).  Complex code can be written using asynchronous IO without it getting unwieldy if you really learn the best techniques for managing it.  For example, you can use promises, the [async library](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) or state machines.